# How to modify sections in my table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a table of contents like this in my document:

[image]

So I would like to get the PART to be bigger and then I would like the section to move more to the right and subsections as well more to the right =) And also I would want only the PART to be bolded

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: You can easily use `titletoc` package.

Comment: +1 Thank you everyone for your answers! I will look them up and find out about the MWE =)